# Calculate pong game vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the resulting vector when the ball hits the paddle. There are 3 scenarios: paddle not moving, paddle moving to the left and to the right.

I thought all I need to do is add both the ball's and paddle's vectors togheter to get the resulting vector. For example the ball is 10 @ 135 deg and the paddle is 20 @ 0 deg, the resulting vector would be like [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B10cos%20135,%2010sin%20135%7D%20%2b%20%7B20%20cos%200,%2020%20sin%200%7D), but if the paddle is going in the other direction -20 @ 0 deg, then it would look like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B10cos%20135,%2010sin%20135%7D%20%2b%20%7B-20%20cos%200,%20-20%20sin%200%7D), which doesn't seem right. Also if the paddle isn't moving at all (0 @ 0 deg) then the ball would just bounce right back not to the right.

So I'm asking what is the right formula to get the needed vector?

Comment: I usually think the formula is add, based on the reflected vector from stationary paddle, a portion of the paddle's horizontal velocity. Some other games also check which part of the paddle the ball hits, and adjust either the horizontal velocity or the reflected angle.

Comment: This depends on whether you want to have a physically realistic simulation. In reality, part of the translational energy would be transformed to rotation of the ball and vice versa. Also, some impulse and energy (and rotation) would be transferred to the paddle. For the simplified case of an "infintely heavy" paddle and a ball that cannot rotate, the horizontal(!) movement of the paddle has no(!) influence on the reflection.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So you want to say that the majority of pong games are physically unrealistic because it's possible to change the ball's direction/angle with the paddle?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a [dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) problem then a linear algebra one. Let the initial velocity vector of the ball be $\vec{v}=(v\cos\theta, v\sin\theta)$ and the initial velocity vector of the paddle be $\vec{V}=(V\cos(\phi), V\sin(\phi))$. Consider the game from the paddle's point of view. In such a frame, the the paddle is stationary, so when the ball hits it, it simply reverses its $\hat{x}$ velocity (since the paddle is effectively a vertical wall.) In the paddle's frame, the velocity vector of the ball is $\vec{v} - \vec{V}=(v\cos\theta - V\cos\phi, v\sin\theta - V\sin\phi)$ which therefore becomes $(V\cos\phi - v\cos\theta, v\sin\theta - V\sin\phi)$ after the collision. Then, all that remains is to switch back to the viewer's frame by adding $\vec{V}$, giving $\vec{v}\,'=(2V\cos\phi - v\cos\theta, v\sin\theta)=(2V_{x}-v_{x},v_{y})$ as the velocity vector of the ball after the collision.

**Comments/Checks:**

One mildly surprising fact is that the vertical velocity of the ball is left unchanged regardless of the motion of the paddle. This is a direct consequence of the fact that the paddle is vertical; the normal to the paddle will always be horizontal, and so it will always apply a horizontal force. This implies that whatever initial vertical velocity the ball has will be left unchanged throughout the round.

If $V=0$, the paddle is stationary, and we find $\vec{v}\,'=(- v_{x}, v_{y})$, exactly a reversal in horizontal direction as expected. If the paddle is moving to the right ($V_{x}>0$) and the ball is moving to the right ($v_{x}>0$), the ball will not hit the paddle unless $v_{x} >V_{x}$. Therefore, $-\infty<2V_{x}-v_{x}<V_{x}.$ Note that this implies that if $V_{x}<v_{x}<2V_{x}$, the ball will continue to move to the right after the collision, but at a speed necessarily slower than the paddle, so it won't hit it again untill the paddle slows down. The same argument applies to both objects moving to the left. If the paddle is moving left, ($V_{x}=-|V_{x}|$) and the ball is moving right $v_{x}=|v_{x}|$, then $2V_{x}-v_{x}=-(2|V_{x}|+|v_{x}|)<0$, so the ball necessarily moves to the left as expected and vice versa for the opposite directions.

Comment: Some games keep track of the spin of the ball, in which case vertical motion of the paddle does matter because it changes the spin imparted.  Otherwise, as you say, it does not.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, one could make the game more exciting by including this effect. I'm sure OP will say whether or not he wanted it to be there.